# PowershellScript ObjectNotFoundException CommandNotFoundException Path

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, sn

I sign my Dlls with SNK-Files. This is done without problems through the visual studio build.

Now i want to validate the DLLs that I really gave them a strong name. I found [this powershell script](http://practicethis.com/script-validate-assemblys-snk-using-powershell/), but I think powershell hates my path.

```
Clear-Host

$path="C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\BuildOutput\Debug"
$snPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\sn.exe"


foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include *.dll, *.exe)
{
    $reportLine = $item.FullName + "," + $item.Extension

#validate integrity
$expression = $snPath + ' -vf "' +  $item.FullName +'"'
$verify = Invoke-Expression $expression
$isValid = $verify | Select-String -Pattern "is valid"

if($isValid)
{
    $reportLine = $reportLine + ",ist signiert"
}
else
{
    $reportLine = $reportLine + ",ist nicht signiert"
}

#extract token
$expression = $snPath + ' -Tp "' +  $item.FullName +'"'
$result = Invoke-Expression $expression

$tokenString = $result | Select-String -Pattern "key token is"
if($tokenString)
{
    $token = $tokenString.Tostring().Substring(20)
    $reportLine = $reportLine + "," +$token
}

    $reportLine
}
```

And my error is

> In Line:1 Character:19
>
> - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1  ...
> - ~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (x86:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I translated more error information.

> The term "x86" was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if the path is correct (if included), and retry.

Do I have to escape the x86? And if yes - How can i do it? I tried [this](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2013/03/powershell-quick-tip-accessing-the-programfilesx86-environment-variable.html).

I tried this with allways the same result.

```
$snPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\sn.exe"

$snPath = ${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)} + "\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\sn.exe"

$snPath =  ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} + "\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\sn.exe"

$snPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)") + + "\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\sn.exe"
```

Powershell Version

Major: 5
Minor: 1
Build: 14393
Revision: 103

**EDIT**

I fixed my snPath

I gave more examples

more error Information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
$expression = $snPath + ' -vf "' +  $item.FullName +'"'
$verify = Invoke-Expression $expression
```

you could do it like that:

`$verify = & $snPath -vf $item.FullName`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i get the same result. I even tried the path again in my windows explorer, but it is the right one.  I don't know why powershell script hates this path so much.

Comment: well I used the same path as you (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\sn.exe`). for me that worked.

Comment: does this command prints something? `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\sn.exe" | Write-Output`

Comment: I am really confused too - why this isnt working. I am fresh into Powershell Scripts. I executed your command and it prints me the possiblitys of sn.exe

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed the other line in the Code and it is  working! Thank you !